# How to add data to an array in another file's variable?

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following variable with an array in `config.php`:

```
$user_password = array(
'admin' => 'phpass:!2a!09!0VacTRBCSGujva0D474.Ce3XI6hEjb80/4VTYKGF0LFx9sIY/BdA.',
'test' => 'phpass:!2a!09!WFA38xA3BBdT.5nJVVMmBOQVAkyuAC/RluiN0ekNPAr0w6d4YBZK2',
'test2' => 'phpass:!2a!09!ZiysPdYPcL3tKpUiVFZLlOVw.l/E4paN6LVDCrRNCsResNex1NUmK' 
);
```

I would like to add a new user from my login page, how would i go about adding new users in the config.php  `$user_password` array ?

Im not really sure how to start.

should i include the file or use require_once then edit the array and in config.php ..?

EG:

```html
if (isset($_REQUIRE['login-btn'])) {
 $username = $_REQUEST['user'];
 $passwd = $_REQUEST['passwd'];
    if (isset($username) && isset($passwd)) {
        //code to add user an passwd to the config variable $user_passwd array
     }
}
```

Comment: if you `include` or `require` you can access and change value of `$user_password`

Comment: This is bad practice! You basically ask how can I write code that changes itself. That is a _huge_ security issue, since if something is not really perfectly secured _any_ code could get written and then executed on your system!

Comment: Out of curiosity why aren't you using a database or something made for this type of thing

Comment: @C2486 That is not what the OP asks...

Comment: If you've got a set of data you need to store in a file (and I agree that a dedicated database would make a lot more sense), then use a format that's more suited for it - JSON, YAML, ini, etc. PHP can read and write these a lot more easily than it can read and write itself.

Comment: @arkascha this code has it via the config so i am re-doing everything, so once the page loads it will auto encrypt those passwords and dump them into a db. i have to update this code since it runs on php5 and im on php7. im breaking down https://yourls.org trying to make it more modern

Comment: @iainn i know using a database makes much more sense but the creator of https:// yourls.org did not think his setup through before coding it, so his config file holds the user names and passwords and im breaking down everything, so i can update the code and change it to a db dependent site.

Comment: @MStart Sure, I get that. But I think moving to another file-based format as a short-term solution will be a lot easier to work this than trying to dynamically add lines to an array in a PHP file. You can wrap up calls to json_decode/file_get_contents to read the existing passwords, and then json_encode/file_put_contents to write them back after you've added a new one.

Comment: @iainn i tried that, the issue is that `YOURLS` auto-encrypts clear text passwords, so then i get a `preg_replace` error

Comment: @MStart Sorry, you've lost me. How does `preg_replace` get involved? MonkeyZeus's answer is basically exactly what I meant.

Comment: @iainn after i enter a username and a passwd then launch the YOURLS engine it overwrites that array and changes all clear text passwords to hashed passwds check : https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS for the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current methodology is quite cumbersome and unnecessarily restricted. You should definitely switch it over to using JSON for easier manipulation and storage:

**config.php**

```
$user_password = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/users.json'));
```

**users.json**

*DO NOT PLACE THIS FILE IN A PUBLICLY ACCESSIBLE LOCATION WHICH WOULD ALLOW ANY VISITOR TO DOWNLOAD IT*

```
{"admin":"phpass:!2a!09!0VacTRBCSGujva0D474.Ce3XI6hEjb80\/4VTYKGF0LFx9sIY\/BdA.","test":"phpass:!2a!09!WFA38xA3BBdT.5nJVVMmBOQVAkyuAC\/RluiN0ekNPAr0w6d4YBZK2","test2":"phpass:!2a!09!ZiysPdYPcL3tKpUiVFZLlOVw.l\/E4paN6LVDCrRNCsResNex1NUmK"}
```

**Adding new user**

```
$user_password[$username] = $passwd;
file_put_contents('/path/to/users.json', json_encode($user_password));
```

---

Note:

Without using a database, this is the proper way to handle the current situation. However, if you start getting tens of thousands of users then this method will only get slower and slower.

Comment: IMHO, i actually prefer working with json. Yes it works :). time to update this code to a db version .